# Extending Android Application class

Tags: class, constants, extends, android

When I was searching for a solution to get the error reports from remote device, just like the test flight app in iOS, I found the `acra` for Android devices [here](http://code.google.com/p/acra/wiki/BasicSetup)

In the basic set up they have said we need to add some lines in `extends Application class`.

In my project so far I have not created such a class, when I was searching in SO regarding this, I came over few questions regarding the `extends Application class`.

I understood that they are saying a Constant class which contains a global variables, have I understood the right way.

In my projects I use to create a class named as `Constants`, which contains some `global variables` such as `Strings, int, ArrayList` and I this class I use to do my `api hits` and `json parsings`. Does this class can be used as `extends Application`.

If it is the same, in the above mentioned link, they have said

```
override the onCreate() method to add the ACRA init statement
```

But so far I have not created a `onCreate` method in my Constant class.  Am I doing the right thing?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I wouldn't bother trying to merge your `Constants` class with this class. It isn't worth the effort. Just create a new class that does what is necessary for ACRA. Like this:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // do the ACRA init here
    }
}
```

Now you need to make sure that your `MyApplication` class gets used. So you need to add `android:name` to the `<application>` tag entry in your manifest like so

```
<application
    android:name="fully.qualified.package.name.MyApplication"
```

Done.

Comment: thanx for your answer, other than the ACRA, anything else needed to be added in MyApplication class regarding my app or the Constant class

Comment: Not that I know of. Refer to the ACRA documentation.