# Android Java - How to run the main method idea?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

So basically im learning android for the first time.
And i have this java file which has all the methods and the main method which runs all these methods and prints out something for me.

I sort of learned some basics such as adding activities into the manifest , using Intent ,creating layouts, creating a menu ,and using some of their override source methods .
But now im stumped on the idea of how do i get my android to run the main method of my java file. Any ideas?

for example , just say my main java file does some sort of calculation or puzzle such as .... the Tower Of Hanoi,or factorisation
and it has a main method which at the end just prints out the answer . How do i get this answer printed out ?

Comment: use log http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android has the concept of event based programming - like most of the graphical interfaces. That means that there's no main method but a lot of methods that get called by Android.

**How do start an Activity?** Android starts Apps with a Launcher. This is the program you use, when you're on the home screen of your device. It uses Intents which in turn trigger your App. Thru the Manifest you define which Activity will be created and the `onCreate` method of this Activity is the first called.

**How to print a result?** Logcat is Androids way to print a message for the programmer. See the `Log` class. The code `Log.d("MyApp", "hello world");` prints it to the log. You can read the log in your programming environment like Eclipse.

**How and where do I put long running code?** Therefore Android has defined the `Service` class. It runs in background and gets started via Intents (again). You can also use Java's threads but they're somewhat outside of Androids priority scheduling. Services (background) and Activities (foreground) communicate with each other in different ways via messages. When a message is received, a Handler is called. Again another method, called by an event.

There's one rule for long running processes in Android: Never run them on the Ui-Thread! They will stop the whole device from reacting on users input.

Do you have the feeling now that an Android program looks like a lot of pieces of a puzzle? Well, you're probably right. But that's the way useri interface programs look like - at least from my experience.

Answer (score 0):

Your onCreate method can be used as your main method. If you want to print something out, you can use System.out.println("Words go here");

Comment: In this case, the print will be stored in your Android device's log and can thus, investigated via the LogCat view of the Android Development tools. If you want to display your result at the view of your Android application instead, try the Android hello world example: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to the main method would be onCreate method in Application class (Application, not Activity!). 
You can read about extending Application class [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12834379/extending-android-application-class). Other than that, jboi answered your question :)