# Where is my android application class file?

Tags: android, facebook, file, class

I was following the instructions on how to implement facebook into my application.  However, I got stuck on this direction: "To automatically log app activation events, add the following code to the onCreate() method of your app's Application class:"

```
  @Override
    public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
  }
```

What does this really mean?  Is the Application class a separate file somewhere in my app or do I include the above code in my MainActivity class file?  I'm confused.  If it is a separate file, where do I find it?

I'm new to programming and often times people give instructions assuming we know 100% what they are talking about.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: here is doc for `Application` class https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

you have to define your `Application` class in manifest's application tag like

    `<application
        android:name="com.example.BaseClass"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">`

and that class will be your application class which holds global application state

Comment: It's a class you would need to create yourself. Just follow the answer on [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12834379/extending-android-application-class), subbing in your Facebook stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Read about Singleton class. It's a app controller class which extends Application and on start of application this class 1st execute.

```
public class AppController extends Application {

    public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();

    private static AppController mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }


}
```

In manifest

```
<application
        android:name=".AppHelper.AppController"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not any Application class in your application.

you must define it yourself. you must add a claas to your application which extends Application (a built in android class that is the entry point of your application).

An application class would be like below:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);       
}
```

}

The you need to tell your app to use your custom application class instead of default built in android Application class. You can do it by changing the name attribute of your application tag in your manifest, like this:

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApp"
    .....
    .....
```