# How avoid Android context in static field in Singleton?

Tags: android, kotlin

In my Android app I need to create singleton with param for service class:

```
class AndroidFileUtil2 private constructor(newContext: Context) {

    init {
        context = newContext
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            Log.d(TAG, "CONSTRUCTOR: context = $context")
    }

    companion object {
        private var instance: AndroidFileUtil2? = null
        private lateinit var context: Context

        private val TAG = AndroidFileUtil2::class.java.name

        @Synchronized
        fun getInstance(context: Context): AndroidFileUtil2 {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = AndroidFileUtil2(context)
            }
            return instance as AndroidFileUtil2
        }

        fun getTest() {
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                Log.d(TAG, "getTest(): context_cacheDir = ${context.cacheDir}")
        }
    }

}
```

and use like this:

```
class Main : Application() {
  override fun onCreate() {
      super.onCreate()
      AndroidFileUtil2.getInstance(appContext)
      AndroidFileUtil2.getTest()
    }

}
```

It's work fine. When I call `AndroidFileUtil2.getTest()` it's success print cache dir of my app. Smt like this:

```
getTest(): context_cacheDir = /data/user/0/com.myproject.client.debug/cache
```

Nice.

But on IDE I get warning like this:

```
Do not place Android context classes in static fields. This is a memory leak
```

in this line:

```
private lateinit var context: Context
```

How fix this warning in my singleton class?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `setContext` method in your static part 
Check here:
[Access application context in companion object in kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54075649/access-application-context-in-companion-object-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 0):

This error is for a generic `Context` because a `Context` could be any short-lived component like an Activity or Service. It will not give you the error for an `Application`, because the Application lives for the entire life of your app. And since an `Application` is a `Context`, you can use it for almost anything you'd be using a `Context` for, so you can change your variable type to `Application` to avoid the warning and prevent the risk of any leaks.

So make the `lateinit var` an `Application`, and make `Application` the argument type for `getInstance()`.

The classes `Activity`, `Service`, and `AndroidViewModel` all have `application` properties you can use to pass into your `getInstance()` function.

But aside from avoiding the Lint warning, it would be appropriate to make `AndroidFileUtil2`'s constructor also use `Application` instead of `Context` since it is a singleton. Lint isn't sophisticated enough to identify that and warn you about it, but as it is defined now, the `AndroidFileUtil2` static reference has just as much risk of causing a leak as the static generic `Context` reference.