# Unable to Add setOnClickListener for RecyclerView items

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

This application uses sharedPreferences to populate the recycler viewer in MainActivity.kt. I would like to then have the two buttons in each recycler item to have an event listener that will go to another activity. However I have been unable to do so, having tried to manipulate the adapter and the MainActivity.kt.

MainActivity.kt:

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import java.io.File

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        populateRecycler()



        //Pressing GPS icon will go to adding a new location
        fabAddLocation.setOnClickListener { view -> addLocation(view) }
        }

    fun addLocation(x:View?){
        val locationIntent: Intent = Intent(this,AddLocation::class.java)
        startActivity(locationIntent)
    }

    fun createRecyclerContent(list :Array<String>): ArrayList<LocationItem> {

        //Get the shared preference file data
        var size = list.size
        val itemList = ArrayList<LocationItem>()
        for (i in 0 until size){
            val name = list[i].substring(0, list[i].length -4)
            lateinit var prefs:SharedPreferences

            prefs = getSharedPreferences(name,Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

            val getTitle = prefs.getString("Title","")
            val getDescription = prefs.getString("Description","")
            val getGps = prefs.getString("Longitude","")+","+prefs.getString("Latitude","")
            val listItem = LocationItem(R.drawable.ic_location_icon,getTitle.toString(),getDescription.toString(),getGps)

            itemList += listItem

        }
        return itemList

    }
    fun populateRecycler(){
        val sharedPrefsDir = File(applicationInfo.dataDir, "shared_prefs")
        if(sharedPrefsDir.exists() && sharedPrefsDir.isDirectory()){
            //verifying that the directory is found and that it has the names
            val locateList = sharedPrefsDir.list();
            //This should be sending the number of recycler items to my createRecyclerContent function, to populate the recycler

            val locationsList = createRecyclerContent(locateList)

            recycler_view.adapter=LocationsAdapter(locationsList)
            (recycler_view.adapter as LocationsAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged()
            recycler_view.layoutManager= LinearLayoutManager(this)
            recycler_view.setHasFixedSize(true)


        }
    }
```

Adapter (LocationsAdapter):

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.ImageButton
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.saved_location_layout.view.*

class LocationsAdapter(private val locationList:List<LocationItem>):RecyclerView.Adapter<LocationsAdapter.LocationViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): LocationViewHolder {
        //passes the layout to the recycler
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.saved_location_layout, parent, false)

        return LocationViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: LocationViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = locationList[position]

        holder.imageButton.setImageResource(currentItem.image)

        holder.textView1.text = currentItem.text1
        holder.textView2.text = currentItem.text2
        holder.textView3.text = currentItem.text3


    }
    //sets the count to the number of locations in the list
    override fun getItemCount() = locationList.size

    class LocationViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

        val imageButton: ImageButton = itemView.btn_location
        val textView1: TextView = itemView.text_view_1
        val textView2: TextView = itemView.text_view_2
        val textView3: TextView = itemView.text_view_3
        val editButton:Button = itemView.btn_edit
    }
}
```

There are two buttons, btn_edit and btn_location, I need to have each to go to another activity. Any help on how do this greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem here: [Access application context in companion object in kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54075649/access-application-context-in-companion-object-in-kotlin)

The issue is largely around getting the correct context from the main activity passed to the adapter. Here is my implementation that is now working:
**MainAcitivity.kt:**

```
open class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        LocationsAdapter.setContext(this)
        populateRecycler()


        //Pressing GPS icon will go to adding a new location
        fabAddLocation.setOnClickListener { view -> addLocation(view) }
    }

    fun addLocation(x: View?) {
        val locationIntent: Intent = Intent(this, AddLocation::class.java)
        startActivity(locationIntent)
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.fade_out)

    }

    fun createRecyclerContent(list: Array<String>): ArrayList<LocationItem> {

        //Get the shared preference file data
        var size = list.size
        val itemList = ArrayList<LocationItem>()
        for (i in 0 until size) {
            val name = list[i].substring(0, list[i].length - 4)
            lateinit var prefs: SharedPreferences

            prefs = getSharedPreferences(name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

            val getTitle = prefs.getString("Title", "")
            val getDescription = prefs.getString("Description", "")
            val getGps = prefs.getString("Longitude", "") + "," + prefs.getString("Latitude", "")
            val listItem = LocationItem(
                R.drawable.ic_location_icon,
                getTitle.toString(),
                getDescription.toString(),
                getGps
            )

            itemList += listItem

        }
        return itemList

    }


    fun populateRecycler() {
        val sharedPrefsDir = File(applicationInfo.dataDir, "shared_prefs")
        if (sharedPrefsDir.exists() && sharedPrefsDir.isDirectory()) {
            //verifying that the directory is found and that it has the names
            val locateList = sharedPrefsDir.list();
            //This should be sending the number of recycler items to my createRecyclerContent function, to populate the recycler

            val locationsList = createRecyclerContent(locateList)

            recycler_view.adapter = LocationsAdapter(locationsList)
            (recycler_view.adapter as LocationsAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged()
            recycler_view.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
            recycler_view.setHasFixedSize(true)


        }

    }
}
*
```

*LocationsAdapter Class file:**

```
class LocationsAdapter(private val locationList:List<LocationItem>):RecyclerView.Adapter<LocationsAdapter.LocationViewHolder>() {

    companion object {
        private lateinit var context: Context

        fun setContext(con:Context){
            context=con
        }
    }
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): LocationViewHolder {

        //passes the layout to the recycler

        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.saved_location_layout, parent, false)

        return LocationViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: LocationViewHolder, position: Int) {



            fun EditALocation(context: Context) {
                val intent = Intent(context, EditLocation::class.java).apply {
                    putExtra("TITLE_DATA",holder.textView1.text.toString())
                }
                context.startActivity(intent)
            }

        val currentItem = locationList[position]


        holder.imageButton.setImageResource(currentItem.image)

        holder.textView1.text = currentItem.text1
        holder.textView2.text = currentItem.text2
        holder.textView3.text = currentItem.text3
        holder.editButton.setOnClickListener {
           EditALocation(context)
        }


    }

    //sets the count to the number of locations in the list
    override fun getItemCount() = locationList.size

    class LocationViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){


        val imageButton: ImageButton = itemView.btn_location
        val textView1: TextView = itemView.text_view_1
        val textView2: TextView = itemView.text_view_2
        val textView3: TextView = itemView.text_view_3
        val editButton:Button = itemView.btn_edit

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use in YourActivity class(Which you want to open from recycler view item button click) and inside companion object**

```
    companion object {

       fun start(context: Context) {
            val intent = Intent(context, "YourActivity"::class.java)
            context.startActivity(intent)
        } 
    }
```

**Inside onBindViewHolder Use below code to call**

```
   override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: LocationViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = locationList[position]

        holder.imageButton.setImageResource(currentItem.image)

        holder.textView1.text = currentItem.text1
        holder.textView2.text = currentItem.text2
        holder.textView3.text = currentItem.text3
       // you can use like this to visit your activity
        holder.editButton.setOnClickListener{
                     YourActivity.start(itemView.context)
             }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I have added this function to my activity class, however I am confused on where I should be calling it in my Viewholder? Could you help clarify that?

Comment: I tried to add to LocationViewHolder:
`class LocationViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        val imageButton: ImageButton = itemView.btn_location
        val textView1: TextView = itemView.text_view_1
        val textView2: TextView = itemView.text_view_2
        val textView3: TextView = itemView.text_view_3
        val editButton:Button = itemView.btn_edit
        val getEditor = editButton.setOnClickListener{
            Edit.(itemView.context)
        }
    }`
But now there is an error: The expression cannot be selector (occur after the dot)

Comment: use holder.editButton.setOnClickListener{} on onBindViewHolder function

Comment: Do you think you could edit your post to show what you mean? I'm still having issues trying to implement. Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

You could create a simple ClickListener for your Adapter, e.g. like this

```
class LocationsAdapter(private val locationList:List<LocationItem>, private val listener: OnLocationButtonClickListener):RecyclerView.Adapter<LocationsAdapter.LocationViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): LocationViewHolder {
        //passes the layout to the recycler
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.saved_location_layout, parent, false)

        return LocationViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: LocationViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = locationList[position]
        holder.bind(currentItem)
    }
    //sets the count to the number of locations in the list
    override fun getItemCount() = locationList.size

    inner class LocationViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

        val imageButton: ImageButton = itemView.btn_location
        val textView1: TextView = itemView.text_view_1
        val textView2: TextView = itemView.text_view_2
        val textView3: TextView = itemView.text_view_3
        val editButton:Button = itemView.btn_edit

        fun bind(item: LocationItem) {

           imageButton.setImageResource(item.image)
           imageButton.setOnClickListener {
              listener.onImageClick(item)
           }
           textView1.text = item.text1
           textView2.text = item.text2
           textView3.text = item.text3
           editButton.setOnClickListener {
              listener.onEditClick(item)
           }
        }

    }


    interface OnLocationButtonClickListener {
       fun onEditClick(item: LocationItem)
       fun onImageClick(item: LocationItem)
    }

}
```

in your activity you just have to implement the listener, override the methods and pass it to your adapter

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnLocationButtonClickListener {

   ...


    fun populateRecycler(){
        val sharedPrefsDir = File(applicationInfo.dataDir, "shared_prefs")
        if(sharedPrefsDir.exists() && sharedPrefsDir.isDirectory()){
            //verifying that the directory is found and that it has the names
            val locateList = sharedPrefsDir.list();
            //This should be sending the number of recycler items to my createRecyclerContent function, to populate the recycler

            val locationsList = createRecyclerContent(locateList)

            recycler_view.adapter=LocationsAdapter(locationsList, this)
            (recycler_view.adapter as LocationsAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged()
            recycler_view.layoutManager= LinearLayoutManager(this)
            recycler_view.setHasFixedSize(true)


        }

        override fun onImageClick(item: LocationItem) {
           ...
        }

        override fun onEditClick(item: LocationItem) {
           ...
        }

    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment! When I try to implement this I am getting an error, here:
` listener.onEditClick(item)`
I am not sure if I should be substituting 'listener' here for something else? This solution otherwise makes sense to me, just not sure how to implement this function. Thanks again for your help

Comment: sorry, i updated my answer, the ViewHolder class needs to be a ```inner class```, then you can use the listener

Comment: Thank you! However no the line:
`recycler_view.adapter=LocationsAdapter(locationsList, this)`
is throwing an error for using 'this'. It is suggesting changing listener to the MainActivity form the adapter? If I make the change then errors get thrown all over the LocationsAdapter. Thanks again for your help

Comment: did you implement the listener in your MainActivity where you create the adapter?