# Android Hilt : How I can inject any object in Object class or singleton class

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

I want to inject application string inside object class `SingletonObject`. I am new in Hilt and not getting any way to inject this

```
object SinglentonObject{
    @AppQualifier
    @Inject
    lateinit var applicationString: String
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The `@Inject` annotation is available only for EntryPoints like `@AndroidEntryPoint`, `@HiltAndroidApp`. As of now, there is no option to inject into a non-entry point classes in Hilt.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use the `@Inject` annotation but, if you still want to have a single source of truth and use Hilt from anywhere, you can create a custom `EntryPoint` and then use the `ApplicationContext` to grab an instance of whatever you are providing with Hilt.

First, you have to declare the `EntryPoint` (it can be added anywhere you want, but the best practice is to keep it closer to where it's used):

```
@EntryPoint
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
interface ApplicationStringInterface {
  @AppQualifier fun getApplicationString(): String
}
```

then you can grab an instance of the `ApplicationString` like this:

```
var applicationString = EntryPoints.get(applicationContext, ApplicationStringInterface::class.java).getApplicationString();
```

If you need help to get an instance of the applicationContext from anywhere, look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54076015/293878